# Auto-scroll textarea in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, textarea, autoscroll

So basically I have this Iframe

```
<iframe src ="http://.../iframe.php" id="myIframe"></iframe>
```

and the only thing on this iframe page (iframe.php) is a textarea:

```
<textarea  id="test" name="text" rows="20" cols="50" readonly>
```

I tried scrolling the textarea down if the value of the textarea exceeds the iframe window (on the page with the Iframe on it) but it just wont work. I tried a few solutions on stackoverflow but nothing worked for me.

**UPDATE**

It's working now. Working code if everyone is interested:

```
function myFunctiontest() {
 var goddammit = document.getElementById('myIframe').contentWindow.document.getElementById('test');
     goddammit.scrollTop = goddammit.scrollHeight;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `oninput="this.scrollTop = this.scrollHeight;"` in the textarea
and if it works do it properly with the event handler.

Update:

In the page that contains the `<iframe>`, it has an id as well as the textarea:

```
window.onload = function () {

    var ifr = document.getElementById('ifr'),
        ta = ifr.contentDocument.getElementById('ta');

    ta.scrollTop = ta.scrollHeight; 

}
```

Comment: the script should run on the container page or on the iframe.php ?

Comment: if it runs on the iframe.php the following works in ff, chrome, safari
 `window.onload = function () {
  var i = document.getElementById('test');
  i.scrollTop = i.scrollHeight;
 }`

Comment: still not working.. I tried this code on the page with the iframe on it let's just call this page test.php. On this test.php I now have your code but its still not working

Comment: strange...here my (working for me) attempt
http://www.freakstyle.it/stack/38307483/